# Does the order of columns in an multicolumn non-clustered index matter in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, non-clustered-index

Does the order of columns in a multi-column nonclustered index created for a SQL Server table really matter?

E.g. Is

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [MultiFieldIndex_1]  
ON [Table_01] ([Column_A],[Column_B],[Column_C],[Column_D])
```

same as

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [MultiFieldIndex_1]  
ON [Table_01] ([Column_D],[Column_C],[Column_B],[Column_A])
```

?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

***YES it matters!***

The index *might* be used, if your query includes the **n left-most** columns of that index.

So with your first version of index `MultiFieldIndex_1`, it *might* be used if you

- use all four columns
- use columns A, B, C
- use columns A, B
- use column A

but it will ***NOT*** ever be considered if you use

- just column D
- columns C and D 
  etc.

However, your second version of the index *might* be used if your specify just `D`, or `D` and `C` - but it will ***never ever*** be used if you just specify `A` and `B`

Only if you **always** use **all columns** that are defined in the index, then the order in which they are defined becomes (almost) irrelevant (there are still some nuances as to ordering by highest selectivity etc. but those are much less important than the fact that an index will not ever be used if you don't specify the n left-most columns in your `SELECT` statements)

Comment: By query you mean the columns in the WHERE clause right ?